# Codeigniter: "Error 1048 Column 'customer_id' cannot be null" Why am I getting this error?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
INSERT INTO `dance_payment` (`customer_id`, `firstname`, `date_of_joining`, `month_of_payment`, `amount`, `receipt_number`) VALUES (NULL, 'David Noronha', '2015-08-07', 'august', '1000', 'pan001')
```

this is the "php" code

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        $data = $this->payment_m->array_from_post(array('customer_id','firstname','date_of_joining','month_of_payment','amount','receipt_number') );


        // $data['date_of_joining']=date_format($data['date_of_joining'],"Y-m-d");
        $data['date_of_joining'] = flip_date($data['date_of_joining'],'SHOW');
        $nid = $this->payment_m->save($data);


        //add customer reminder
        $this->load->model('customer_course_m');
        $selected_course = $this->input->post('courses');

        $this->db->delete('dance_customer_course', array('customer_id' => $nid ) );

        //insert festival
        if(is_array($selected_course) && count($selected_course) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($selected_course as $kf => $vf) 
            {
                $course_data['customer_id'] = $nid;
                $course_data['festival_id'] = $vf;
                $this->customer_course_m->save($course_data);
            }
        }

        //end of  customer reminder
        if($id)
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Payment details added successfully.');
        redirect('customer');
    }
```

that is the code in codeigniter, can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong or where should i check for the reason of this error, I am really bad at codeigniter, help would be really appreciated. It has been troubling me for the past 2 days, Thanks :)

Comment: post the schema for the table dance_payment, that should shed some light

Answer (score 0):

```
Error 1048 Column 'customer_id' cannot be null”
```

Its showing because of following reasons

1. customer_id is unique in database schema
2. customer_id is set as not null in database schema

**If you want customer_id pass as Null then make it auto increment (If customer_id is primary key its good option)**

As you are calling following model (if you share model code also its better)

```
$nid = $this->payment_m->save($data);
```

check what value your are getting in $nid.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but, the problem is I need to fetch the customer id from another table in order to store this data onto another table, foreign key has already been added.

Comment: share your model also..Can you print $nid = $this->payment_m->save($data); check value of $nid

Comment: which part of the model do you need?

Comment: $this->payment_m->save($data);